# Usages of plural form "человек"

Tags: грамматика

Why do we say "100-200 человек" and not the plural form "люди"?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Человек** here works as a *unit of measure* (how many?  1 человек - 100 человек - 200 человек...) which needs to have a *singular* form in particular (for usage as **1 человек**). Since the word **люди** only has *plural* form, it can't work as a *unit of measure* (is uncountable).

Answer (score 3):

Люди,народ — uncountable noun(only plural?), so they cannot be applied to a specific number.
You can say: людей/народу было человек 100-200.
Or you can say for an indefinite number: Людей/народа было мало(много).

Comment: Going from your example, can you say for example годов прошло лет 100-200 or something?

Comment: No. It's just "прошло лет 100-200" or "годов прошло 100-200". The last one sounds outdated.  **год** и **лет** are countable, means the same, but **год** is used when the number ends in 1 ... 4; **лет** — when the number ends in 0; 5 ... 9. — (...)1 год, (...)2/3/4 года, (...)5/6/7/8/9/0 лет.  If you need an uncountable noun for a time interval - it's just **время**. "времени прошло лет 100-200".  PS: (...)11/12/13/14 is also **лет**

Comment: @Eugene but 1 человек, 3 человека, 5 человек. "людей" is really used when number is very rough and approximate. And even this is not a strict rule. '`На земле живёт примерно 7 миллиардов человек". Uncountable is about another grammar aspect, though.

Comment: Я не уверен, что понимаю, о чём вы. Речь идёт об основном ответе или  моём ответе на комментарий Wilson? **1 человек, 3 человека, 5 человек** - здесь нельзя слово "человек" заменить на "людей". **Людей было мало/много, толпа/сборище людей** - здесь нельзя слово "людей" заменить на "человек". Это я пытался показать в своём ответе для Simona Sorrentino. 1 год, 3 года, 11 лет, 13 лет - здесь разница в употреблении в зависимости от последней цифры(двух последних цифр) числа.

Answer (score 0):

We use человек after **numerals** and we use людей after a **noun** which looks like a number.

> Сто человек, but сотня/сотни людей.

So after десяток, сотня, сотни, тысячи, миллионы (without mentioning how many) use only людей.

If there's an adjective between the numeral and the noun , you should use людей

> пять незнакомых людей 
>   So it's a bit more complicated.

Comment: Agree in general, but e.g. "На земле живёт примерно 7 миллиардов человек" seems completely natural for me.

Comment: А кто против? Это числительное,  так что все правильно

Answer (score -1):

The word люди is plural, therefore it cannot be measured.